# better scrapy skill:how to use scrapy itemloader nest to output a list of dict rather than a dict of list

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to use scrapy itemloader,I used to just item,I want my code lesser
for example:
if I want to parse a list of car info from a page,I need car_name,car_color...but for some car ,the color is None,
I used to write like this:

```
cars = response.xpath(carsxpath)
for car in cars:
    car_name = car.xpath(car_name_xpath)
    car_color = car.xpath(car_color_xpath)
    item = CarItem()
    item['car_name'] = car_name
    item['car_color'] = car_color
    yield item
```

but recently,I found Itemloader,it can simplify the codes up,from document,I found it works like this:

```
loader = ItemLoader(item={}, response=response)
carloader = loader.nested_xpath('car_xpath')
carloader.add('car_name', car_name_xpath)
carloader.add('car_color', car_color_xpath)
cars = loader.load_item()
```

as I found it don't need a tmp var like car_name,car_color before,but use this come to a problem,the cars is a dict of list ,like

```
cars = {'car_name':[car_names],'car_color':[car_colors]}
```

but this is inconvinient for yield the items,I want to get the output like

```
cars = [{'carname':carname1,'carclor':carcolor1'}, {'carname':carname2,'carclor':carcolor2'}...]
```

so my question is ’is there any way to deal with this in scrapy itself?‘,if I need to process more,I would rather use the way I used to ,not the Itemloader

Answer (score 0):

You can specify some processors to your ItemLoader that will do something to the value once it's added to the item loader. For example when the item is added take only the first element:

```
from scrapy.loader.processors import TakeFirst()

loader = ItemLoader(item={}, response=response)
carloader = loader.nested_xpath('car_xpath')
carloader.car_name_out = TakeFirst()
carloader.add('car_name', car_name_xpath)
carloader.car_color_out = TakeFirst()
carloader.add('car_color', car_color_xpath)
cars = loader.load_item()
```

More elegantly it would look like:

```
class MyLoader(ItemLoader):
    default_item_class = dict
    car_name_out = TakeFirst()
    car_color_out = TakeFirst()

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    loader = MyLoader(item={}, response=response)
    carloader = loader.nested_xpath('car_xpath')
    carloader.add('car_name', car_name_xpath)
    carloader.add('car_color', car_color_xpath)
    cars = loader.load_item()
```

Comment: I guess you don't get my points,I know TakeFirst() or other processor,my question is if I code like that ,the output would be a dict of list like:
{'carname':[car1,car2],'carcolor':[car1,car2]}
but normally,we want to yield the items,so I need output like:
[{'name':car1,'color:'color1'},{'name':'car2','color':'color2'}]
so I can take the items easily

Comment: @Tarjintor I'm confused, the code piece at the very beginning of your question already does that. `scrapy.Item` is just an extension of python's dictionary, so you'll get whatever you assign to a key - whether it's a list, string or an integer.

Comment: I see that,I guess I missunderstand the nest_xpath means,@mizhgun solution is my anwser now,thank you

Answer (score 0):

`ItemLoader` is designed to populate single item, not the list of them, so it is better to use something like this:

```
for sel in response.xpath('car_xpath'):
    l = ItemLoader(selector=sel)
    l.add_xpath('car_name', car_name_xpath)
    l.add_xpath('car_color', car_color_xpath)
    yield l.load_item()
```

And that exactly merges your previous approach and usage of ItemLoader.

Comment: this is what I am doing now,I misunderstand the meaning of xpath_nest